# Local history with pry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pry

I'm using the `pry` REPL for ruby, and its rails plugin (the gem `pry-rails`). Currently `pry` has a global history for all projects. Is it possible to configure it such that each rails project will have its own history file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are instructions for this on the Pry wiki under [history](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Customization-and-configuration#history), here's the relevant part for what you want:

> Example: Put the history file in the current directory, for a separate history per-project:
>
> Permanently (in a .pryrc file)
>
> ```
> Pry.config.history.file = ".pry_history"
> ```

Comment: Now it is `Pry.config.history_file`

Answer (score 1):

create a new class like this

```
class Utils
  def self.pry_history
    # path = Pry.config.history.file # old pry version
    path = Pry.config.history_file # new pry version
    valuef = `cat -n #{path}`
    print valuef
  end
end
```

then in your pry console you can do

```
pry(main)> Utils.pry_history
```

Comment: Pry.config.history_file # new pry version